# Swiper.js not able to render the 'Apex-Chart'-Series when swipe between (first to last) or (last to first) slide

Tags: html, charts, slide, apex, swiper.js

I'm facing an unknown issue only when I'm swiping between last (swiper-slide) to first (swiper-slide) and same as first to last, but when I do just a half swipe, then the RedialBar looks good.

I set the **loop: true**. I have 3 Slides. Inside all Slide, i have a very simple APEX RadialBar/Circle Chart's. Everything works nice. But when I slide 1 to 2 Good. 2 to 3 Good. But when I slide 3 to 1 then the RadialBar series does not render. And same problem when I slide 1 to 3. So if I just do a half slide (just a little swipe), then the RadialBar render perfectly.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    //initialize swiper when document ready
    var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
        // Optional parameters
        direction: 'horizontal',
        loop: true,
        pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination',
            type: 'bullets',
            clickable: true
        },
        effect: 'slide'
    })
   
    mySwiper.on('slideChange', function () {
        console.log('slide changed');
      });
});

// Apex Chart
let options = {
    series: [50],
    chart: {
    height: 200,
    type: 'radialBar',
        },
            plotOptions: {
                radialBar: {
                    hollow: {
                    size: '70%',
                }
            },
    },
    
    stroke: {
        lineCap: 'round'
      },
    labels: ['Country'],
};

let chart = new ApexCharts(
    document.querySelector("#demo-chart-1"),options
);
let chart2 = new ApexCharts(
    document.querySelector("#demo-chart-2"),options
);
let chart3 = new ApexCharts(
    document.querySelector("#demo-chart-3"),options
);
chart.render();
chart2.render();
chart3.render();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #a3d5d3;
}
.india,
.canada,
.japan {
  height: 100;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <!-- Slide 1-->
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <section class="india">
        <p class="gas-header">INDIA</p>
        <div id="demo-chart-1"></div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <!-- Slide 2-->
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <section class="canada">
        <p class="gas-header">CANADA</p>
        <div id="demo-chart-2"></div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <!-- Slide 3-->  
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <section class="japan">
        <p class="gas-header">JAPAN</p>
        <div id="demo-chart-3"></div>
      </section>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- If we need pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Again a little request for any help please..

Comment: May, my question is not clear or difficult to answer, but still awaiting the solution if any one like to help or share some tips that where anything wrong in the code. Deeply appreciate if someone extend his/her technicals.